# Using python how can I separate lines of text using pattern matching and store them into different text file

Tags: python, regex, nlp, python-re

Below is the example of code, it's a long log but I have just pasted a snippet of it.
I need to extract lines that comes between a patter ---------------------------------- and store each information in a separate text file for every respectively.

```
Like:
------------------
info1 
------------------
info2
------------------
info3
------------------
```

Output:

```
fetch info1 and store it into file1.txt
fetch info2 and store it into file2.txt
fetch info3 and store it into file3.txt
And so on...
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
**This is the text data   :** 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

revision88 106 | rohit | 2018-06-08 13:41:46 +0530 (Fri, 08 Jun 2018) | 1 line

initial code import from FinanavialAnalytics branch


------------------------------------------------------------------------
revision88 99 | dhammdip.sawate | 2018-06-04 20:59:48 +0530 (Mon, 04 Jun 2018) | 1 line

Added Little Bit Java Support.!

Index: resources.properties
===================================================================
--- resources.properties    (revision 98)
+++ resources.properties    (revision 99)
@@ -1,15 +1,15 @@
 ####################Elastsic Search#########################
 ElasticClusterName=UProbe
-ElasticHost=192.168.0.91
+ElasticHost=192.168.0.73
 ElasticPort=19300
 
-esSQLURL=http://192.168.0.91:19200/_sql?sql=
+esSQLURL=http://192.168.0.73:19200/_sql?sql=
 resultsize =1024

@@ -72,45 +72,65 @@
 secfile /home/sandeep/Desktop/LIC/Uprobe-LIC/Uprobe-Dev.seed
 licfile /home/sandeep/Desktop/LIC/Uprobe-LIC/Uprobe-Dev.lic
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
revision88 | sandeep.yadav | 2018-05-31 15:31:26 +0530 (Thu, 31 May 2018) | 1 line

Acc_Ref Data front-end side functionality with validation done.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what errors did you get?

Comment: Unable to think of any logic that I should go with. Though trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lg = open("log.txt")
fl = open("temp.txt", 'w')
cnt = 0

for i in lg:
    if i == "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n":
        fl.close()
        cnt += 1
        fl = open("file{}.txt".format(str(cnt)), 'w')
    else:
        fl.write(i)

fl.close()
lg.close()
```

This can be done without even using regex.

Comment: Getting error on this line `fl.open("file{}.txt".format(str(cnt)), 'w')` that **AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'**

Comment: add `\n` in pattern too

Comment: Yes, after adding newline character, it works.

Comment: Thanks @edusankerdk code is working well. Let me test it on a thousand lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed, the main text file is in the same directory with the name 'text.txt' and you want to save the files in the same directory. Please change the file paths according to your needs.This should work for you :

```
with open('./text.txt', 'r') as content:
    paragraphs = list(filter(lambda x : x != '', content.read().split('------------------------------------------------------------------------')))
    for index, para in enumerate(paragraphs):
        filepath = './new_file' + str(index) + '.txt'
        with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
            file.write(para)
```

Comment: You're welcome :) . If you found the answer helpful please consider upvoting and accpeting the answers to keep the StackOverflow circle intact :)

Comment: indeed :) though I can't upvote your solution, I need at least 15 reputation for that, once I will reach there I will surely do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the log file is not too large (e.g. 1GB), you can do it with:

```py
with open('log.log') as f:
    content = f.read()
content = content.split('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
for idx, info in enumerate(content):
    with open('info{}.txt'.format(idx + 1), 'w') as f:
        f.write(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the "========..." was also one of the patterns, hence i used re module... So with this you could add more patterns if need be
[originally had re.compile("-+|=+")]

```py
import re

with open("file.txt", "r") as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()
    regex = re.compile("-+")
    mo = regex.findall(text)

text = text.split("\n")
mo_wanted_patterns = [pattern for pattern in mo if len(pattern) > 5]
print(mo_wanted_patterns)

output_text = []
for index,line in enumerate(text):
    if line in mo_wanted_patterns:
        filepath = 'new_file' + str(index) + '.txt'
        
        with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
            file.write("\n".join(output_text))

        output_text = []

    elif line not in mo_wanted_patterns:
        output_text.append(line)
```

**EDIT:** I noticed its a far more complicated code than others have provided. Implementing regex made things more complicated, would be curious to know if it works for you though